# Angularjs ui-sortable - _connectedSortables is undefined

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui-sortable

I have 2 sortable lists and I'm trying to connect them so that I can drag items from one list to the other.  When I drag an item I get an error in sortable.js.  callbacks.update is referencing ui.item.sortable._connectedSortables but it is undefined so when it gets to the getElementScope function, it throws the error.

**UPDATE**

I little more background as to how I got here.  Initially, I had this working. I setup a draggable list and connected it to the sortable list and all was working fine. The issue I had then was when dragging within the sortable list, the model wasn't getting updated.  Once I added the ui-sortable tag the model started getting updated when reordering the list, but after that change is when the previous mentioned error started happening.  The differences between the 2 pieces of code are in the first example I am setting up the sortable like this:

```
$('#testQuestionsTEI').sortable({//code});
```

and there was no ui-sortable attribute in the markup.  Now I have ui-sortable="sortable" in the markup and have $scope.sortable = {//code}.

The first list I have is the accepting list.

```
<div id ="testQuestionsTEI" class="connectedSortable" ui-sortable="sortable" ng-model="test.questions" style="overflow-x:auto; overflow-y: scroll">
                            <div class="TestQuestion" ng-repeat="currQuestionObj in test.questions" style="border:1px solid;padding:7px 7px 7px 7px;margin-top:3px;margin-bottom:3px">
                                <!--do some stuff-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

The js to setup the sortable is here...

```
 $scope.sortable = {
    placeholder: 'questionPlaceholderTEI',
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
    start: function (event, ui) {
        ui.item.startPos = ui.item.index();                 //add startPos to item to use in stop event
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        //Do stuff
        }

    },
    update: function (event, ui) {
        //Do stuff
    }
};
```

The 2nd list is built after an ajax call and the html for it is...

```
<div id="SearchResultItems" ui-sortable="sortable" class="col-md-12 connectedSortable" style="border:1px solid;padding:0 5px 0 5px;" ng-cloak>
<div class="SearchResultItem" index="{{currQuestionObj.id}}" QuestionID="{{currQuestionObj.questionId}}" ngc-done="'setupDraggableItems'" ng-repeat="currQuestionObj in ItemSearchResult.questions" style="border:1px solid;padding:7px 7px 7px 7px;margin-top:3px;margin-bottom:3px" >
    <!--more stuff-->
</div>
```

After the data is returned I setup the draggable and sortable

```
function setupDraggableItems() {
$('div.SearchResultItem').draggable({
    revert: 'clone',
    scroll: false,
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
    appendTo: 'body',
    connectToSortable: '#testQuestionsTEI',
});

$('#SearchResultItems').sortable({
    placeholder: 'questionPlaceholderTEI',
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable'
});
}
```

I have also tried without the .draggable and I get a different error.  In callbacks.update there is a reference to ui.item.sortable.isCanceled() and the error is "Object doesn't support property or method 'isCanceled'

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was that when creating the sortables the 2 different ways I was doing them were actually different implementations.  One was using Jquery-ui directly and the other was angular's ui-sortable.  So I went back to using $('#testQuestionsTEI').sortable which users Jquery-ui.  The other issue where the model wasn't getting updated was fixed by calling $scope.$apply().